# using child process from express giving buffer error

Tags: javascript, python, express, mern, child-process

I am trying to make an application where a user uploads a document and the python script kept in server side in mern stack code will execute using child process and return true or false. But when I opening the image in python file using PIL library it is executing "stderr" method.

here this is how I am calling a child process

```
const {spawn}=require('child_process');
const ls=spawn('python',['scripts/dobChecker.py','/idProof/testadhar.jpg'])
ls.stdout.on('data',(data)=>{
    console.log(`stdoutput ${data}`);
});
ls.stderr.on('data',(data)=>{
    console.log(`stderror`,data);
    
});
ls.on('close',(code)=>{
    console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

I am passing the file name from sysargv and and trying to open in the pyhton file using "Image.open()"
here is the snippet of python I am using :

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import re
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
total_path=sys.argv[1]
img = Image.open(total_path)
img = img.convert('L')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
match=re.search(r'(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|[1][0-2])/[0-9]+',text)
dob=datetime.strptime(match.group(),'%d/%m/%Y').date()
todaydate=datetime.now()
processedTodayDate=todaydate.date()
diffInAge=relativedelta(processedTodayDate,dob)
if(diffInAge.years >= 18):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

and when I start the server using "npm start" command the child process giving error

> stderror <Buffer 54 72 61 63 65 62 61 63 6b 20 28 6d 6f 73 74 20 72 65 63 65 6e 74 20 63 61 6c 6c 20 6c 61 73 74 29 3a 0d 0a 20 20 46 69 6c 65 20 22 73 63 72 69 70 74 ... 282 more bytes>
> child process exited with code 1

Answer (score 0):

I strongly advise you perform a few changes which in turn will increase your ability to comprehend what is truly going on with your attempt.

The primary reason you are not informed well on your attempt is the fact that you are launching a child process and hooking into its raw file descriptors thereby ending up receiving raw information in binary format.

Converting the output of file descriptors and wrapping your python script into a try-except block to get more information instead of crashing should be helpful and hopefully lead you to the core of the issue